# How to judge a USIM card in a mobile data module(WCDMA) is out of balance?

Tags: 3g, at-command, dial-up

I used a 3G(WCDMA) mobile data modern, which dail up in embedded linux, sometimes I find the USIM card is out of balance, so it can't dialup normal, I just search the modern manual to find the AT command can be help.

I use command called "SYSINFO", but it doesn't work. 
whether or not it have a method to judge the USIM status which is out of ballanace.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to dial a USSD command. This is different for each operator.

For example, on Vodafone UK it's *#1345# - on other networks it can be *100#

Depending on your modem, you will need to send

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*100#",15
```

or

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*100#"
```